# I deleted a downvoted post but my account reputation is still behind after one hour. Why?

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, down-votes

I recently posted an answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55756433/php-is-not-connecting) question, which got downvotes, so I deleted [it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55756451/4354201). But I didn't get the reputation points back even after one hour.

This seems to be a bug, since the documentation says to wait 5-15 minutes.

Comment: Note to others: the official documentation says to wait 5-15 minutes; that it hasn't updated after one hour is a bug.

Comment: @SonictheWizardWerehog what should I do now, to regain my points?

Comment: This bug report is fine. Keep in mind that it is currently night time in the United States, and a holiday weekend is approaching.

Comment: @RobertLongson, no, as you can see in my page I only have 21 rep points today, but I gained a upvote and a accepted answer today. which is 25.

Comment: To close voters: even though their reputation has synced back again, it's still a good idea to keep this open, so that SE staff can answer this with info regarding a potential outage. The fact that the reputation wasn't updated after one full hour represents a bug that *may still be there*; it's possible that it's only "fixed" because the global recalc script (which runs once per day) fixed it, *not* the usual one that runs every few minutes.

Comment: I got my rep points back just now!!

Comment: is there anything I missed in this question?

Comment: This question is positively scored. Some people thought your question was insignificant, but they were clearly unaware of the real issue.

Comment: Likely just the scheduler got behind somewhere. Your reputation was eventually recalced because of that specific event.

Comment: @SonictheWizardWerehog There is no script that just updates everyone's rep once per day. That would be prohibitively expensive to run. Rep recalcs are only event-based (something has to happen on your account, like a deletion, to schedule one). Devs can manually trigger global recalcs if they made some major corrective change to the way reputation works, but that is extremely rare.